# CSS: Making div resizable

Tags: html, css, layout, resize, flexbox

Let assume that I have a flex layout and want to make it resizable.

I want to be able to resize one div just by dragging his border horizontally.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pddqrfav/24/)

HTML

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  .flex {
    width: 100%;
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background: red;
      overflow: auto; resize: horizontal;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="flex">ABC</div>
  <div class="flex">
    DEF
  </div>
  <div class="flex">GHI</div>
</div>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: auto; resize: both;`? It should work but may act a bit strange on elements using the flexbox model.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes That's how it looks: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pddqrfav/24/)

Answer (score 1):

check this plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/sxs6RLXVV6REzQnipfgj?p=preview

```
$( "#second" ).resizable();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've got a few problems regarding your solution: Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pddqrfav/19/). Also it says that `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is not a function` even though it technically works.

Answer (score 1):

You should be follow this code

```
#main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100vh;
    .flex {
        width: 100%;
        &:nth-child(2) {
            background: red;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pddqrfav/21/). I guess the flexbox layout leads to that result.